# how to use TSQL syntax to restore .bak to new db?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, restore

I know that there are many similar questions in stackoverflow, but non of them totally satisfied my request?

> 1 - I DO NOT WANT TO ATTACH A DATABASE that contains 2 .mdf .ldf files
>   2 - The file is only a single .bak file
>   3 - i don`t want to use Microsoft SQL Management.
>   4 - i need it to be done programmatically ?( in my case c#)

Comment: THIS IS NOT OFF TOPIC, CANT U SEE

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can restore a database by sending a T-SQL command (the same you would send a `select` query).  For example:

```
restore database NameOfYourDb
from    disk = 'c:\backups\NameOfYourDb.bak'
with    recovery,
        move 'NameOfYourDb_Data' to 'c:\data\NameOfYourDb.mdf',
        move 'NameOfYourDb_Log' to 'c:\data\NameOfYourDb.log'
```

Two is the smallest number of files that can be stored in a .bak file.  Every database has at least one data and one log file (with extension .mdf and .log respectively.)

Note that a restore is done by the SQL Server service.  You have to supply the paths from the point of view of that service.  The account SQL Server is running under needs read access to the .bak file and write access to the .mdf and .log files.

Comment: restoring to .ldf also seems to work

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SMO Objects in the .NET library.  There is a restore object [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore.aspx) that you can use to restore a database.  SQL Server Management Studio is built using this SMO objects, so anything you can do with SSMS you can do with C#.